Error: Failed to load Stripe.js in react app
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/issues/26 - the relevant github issues page, however the thread seems closed with stripe team not responding to also getting this issue... messages over last year. Maybe there's a workaround to waiting for Stripe to fix the issue.
frontend react package.json
"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.6.2",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.0.10",

backend node package.json
"stripe": "^14.21.0",

How we load stripe in our react app, using our custom CheckoutFormWrapper component to call loadStripe, and then to return {children} in the <Elements stripe={stripePromise}> component. The config.stripePublishableKey is correctly set.
import React from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import config from '../../../config';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(config.stripePublishableKey);
const CheckoutFormWrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            {children}
        </Elements>
    );
};

export default CheckoutFormWrapper;

Here is the Sentry Error itself with code snippet, albeit not too helpful.
Error: Failed to load Stripe.js
mechanism, onunhandledrejection, handled: false

../node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/index.mjs in <anonymous> at line 52:16

var onErrorListener = null;
var onLoadListener = null;
var onError = function onError(reject) {
  return function () {
    reject(new Error('Failed to load Stripe.js'));
  };
};
var onLoad = function onLoad(resolve, reject) {
  return function () {

Issue is not exclusive to Mobile Safari, but 36 of 54 sentry events were mobile safari 16.X or 17.X as the browser. Anything anyone can recommend that I do here to improve our code, to get stripe JS to stop failing to load causing these issues in sentry? One idea I have is to wrap loadStripe() in a trycatch that repeats 3 times, not sure if this will help or not or even cause more issues:
const [stripe, setStripe] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const initializeStripe = async () => {
        try {
            const stripeInstance = await loadStripe(config.stripePublishableKey);
            setStripe(stripeInstance);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to load Stripe.js:", error);
            setError("Failed to load payment processing functionality. Please try again later.");
        }
    };
    initializeStripe();
}, []);


Retrying loadStripe likely won't help, see: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/pull/518#issuecomment-1852922754 -- the real thing you need to do is be able to reproduce the issue and then the culprit can be determined and you should reach out to Stripe Support or the Github issue with those details. It is very possible that this continues to be an extension issue.

Thank you for sharing the additional github issue. Tough problem indeed.
